# Is quasiquote removed from scala 3?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm reading [metaprogramming manual on Scala 3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html) and didn't find quasiqotes that I heavily use in my current project. What is the alternative for deconstructuring trees like that:

```
def impl(c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    
    val someTree = //...
    someTree match {
        case typedef @ q"$mods type $name[..$tparams] >: $low <: $high" =>
            //...
        
    }
}
```

How to port such code with tree deconstructioning to Scala 3?

Comment: While I don't have the answer to this question and I am curious myself, Quill's author did a research about porting Quill macros to Doobie in https://github.com/deusaquilus/dotty_test - perhaps by importing this in IDE and reading the code you might find what kind of solutions author used when the way of metaprogramming in Scala changed completely.

Comment: (sorry for my previous comment. i deleted). you might have more luck if you ask here: https://gitter.im/lampepfl/dotty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match on `Expr`s in Scala 3:

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#pattern-matching-on-quoted-expressions